# Why comments in vim have different highlight color than intended?

Tags: vim

As you can see in this screenshot comments in lines 18,20 and 23 are different than lines 9,10,13,14 etc.

Why is this happening? 
Note that, All colorschemes are doing the same. Wrong highlignting for those lines.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: 1. What is your terminal ? 2. What colorsheme do you use ? 3. Do you have any plugin running ? Note: it is working fine for me (in gnome-terminal/no plugin)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 19.04, The terminal is GNOME, Theme is Atom Dark and two plugins - Vim Airline and Vim Airline Themes.